# how UILongPressGestureRecognizer works

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to understand how the gesture recognizer works and trying to get a gesture recognizer to tell me when a long touch BEGINS and when it ENDS even if the touch does not move.

In `viewDidLoad`, I add a subview called game.
In game, I have implemented two ways to recognize touches. One works but does not do what I want. The other does not work.

**Method1** I just added two methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Began");
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event {
    NSLog(@"Ended");
}
```

This worked, without instantiating a gesture recognizer. Can someone tell me why?

The issue with this is that `- (void)touchedEnded:` only gets called if the touch moved and not if the touch ended at the same location it started.   So if I touched and moved and let go, both functions get called. If I touch and hold and let go (without moving), only the `- (void)touchesBegan` gets called.

**METHOD 2**
I instantiated a gesture recognizer:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lprg;
```

then in my setup:

```
self.lprg = [UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
```

then:

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"Handling");
    switch (recognizer.state) {
     case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
         // ...
    }
}
```

But this one, where I programmatically instantiated the recognizer, did not work. I never got any NSLog output in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use this code to intialized gesture

```
  UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture1 = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(celllongpressed:)];
    [gesture1 setDelegate:self];
    [gesture1 setMinimumPressDuration:1];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:gesture1];
```

and to target method use this

```
-(void)celllongpressed:(UIGestureRecognizer *)longPress
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.   Can you tell me how your suggestion is different from my "METHOD 2" other than having both the declaration and allocation & initialization on one line?  I will try it though...

Comment: Not sure if this answer was edited... but YES... the `[self addGestureRecognizer:gesture1];` was my missing piece. Sorry if I missed it when you first replied.   Thanks for replying !

Comment: because you have to add your gesture to your self GestureRecognizer for recognise it.

Comment: There are changes in iOS8: in iOS7 I was able to get the position of the poped view via LongPress...in iOS8 not anymore

Answer (score 4):

All subclasses of UIResponder (which UIView is) respond to touchesBegan, that's why you don't have to do anything and you get it for free.  However it is far from a gesture recognizer.  At a high level gesture recognizers track a lot of things, fore example state.  Sure you can use touches began, but imagine extending that to pick up something like a three finger long press, swipe or pinch.  Things get ugly quick.  Installing a gesture recognizer simplifies things.

For example a long press:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
longPress.numberOfTouchesRequired = 3;
[longPress addTarget:self action:@selector(longPressDetected:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

**Edit**

To implement the delegate:

In your implementation file (.m) add the line  at the end of your @implemation line.  It should look something like

```
 @implementation ViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

Then after you alloc and init your gesture recognizer set the delegate as follows

```
 longPress.delegate = self;
```

Then implement as many methods as you need from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html.  For example you might consider these two

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.    One item you point out that I did not have is the '"[self addGestureRecognizer:longPress]"'.    Unfortunately, this does not seem to work for me either? No errors... but the function never gets called... ??

Comment: Make sure you also set the number of taps required, 1 is probably what your looking for.  If that still doesn't work then it would be helpful to have more context as to where your using it.  For example scrollviews and tableviews have their own gesture recognizers that can interfere with yours.  If that's the case try implementing the UIGesturerecognizer delegate methods and setting yourself as the delegate on it to see what's going on.

Comment: In my Main View Controller, I do: ` Game* game = [[Game alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]; [self.view addSubview:game]; [game setup];`   Then in game.m, in the `-(void) setup {}`, implement the code above.  I have no buttons yet or anything in the current view yet except for `[self addGestureRecognizer:lprg];`.   I wanted to get this gesture recognizer working first.   I have `lprg.numberOfTapsRequired  = 1;` but that did not help any...

Comment: So some of these are probably obvious but are worth asking.  Is the frame being set to something big enough to touch?  If the frame is something like (0,0,0,0) then the recognizer won't work.  Are you performing a long press with the correct number of fingers?  Is there another view that's covering your game view?  If none of those are the problems what happens when you implement the gesture recognizer delegate?

Comment: Actually... this is a brand spanking new project.  The View Controller referenced above  is the main View Controller.  For fun, in the game.m, I did an NSLog of self.frame.size.height & Width and got 480,320.  No other code. Really... :).   How would I implement a delegate?

Comment: See Edit on how to implement the delegate

Comment: Just putting <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> on my @implementation line results is: `@implementation declaration can not be protocol qualified`.

Comment: One more thought: I'm using the IOS Simulator... it worked for my method1 above so I'm assuming that it should work for long touches as well.  no using accelerometer or anything :).

Comment: Cough... Cough.... Cough.... well.... uummmmm... this is embarrassing... but it works now.  I did not touch anything !  I swear.   I tried to implement you "Edit" but it gave the error I mentioned above and now it works.  I just works.  **THANKS !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**